# Python Splinter issue

Tags: python, browser, splinter, well-formed

I just installed Splinter, input simple code like below but have error. Can someone help me on this? Thanks.

```
from splinter import Browser

b=Browser()
url = "http://www.google.com"

b.visit(url)
```

Error messages:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "", line 1, in
>      File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/splinter/driver/webdriver/**init**.py",
>   line 184, in visit
>       self.driver.get(url)   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py",
>   line 245, in get
>       self.execute(Command.GET, {'url': url})   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py",
>   line 233, in execute
>       self.error_handler.check_response(response)   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py",
>   line 194, in check_response
>       raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace) selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Target URL
>   www.google.ca is not well-formed. Stacktrace:
>       at FirefoxDriver.prototype.get (file:///tmp/tmpsIlz0H/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/driver-component.js:10636)
>       at DelayedCommand.prototype.executeInternal_/h (file:///tmp/tmpsIlz0H/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.js:12661)
>       at DelayedCommand.prototype.executeInternal_ (file:///tmp/tmpsIlz0H/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.js:12666)
>       at DelayedCommand.prototype.execute/< (file:///tmp/tmpsIlz0H/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.js:12608)

Comment: Do you have Firefox installed?

Comment: The code you provided is not the one that generated the exception. The exception means that the provided URL "www.google.ca" is missing the protocol "http://" in front.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
from splinter import Browser
with Browser() as b:
    b.visit("http://www.google.com")
```

Docs here: https://splinter.readthedocs.org/en/latest/#sample-code

The method above handles quitting the browser. Your method, also in the docs, should work (it works for me). Try it again, I've noticed I get almost the same error as yours, if my url is "www.google.com". Make sure you have "http://" part.

> selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Target URL
>   www.google.com is not well-formed